# Handling exception thrown when font path not set in PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, exception, phpspreadsheet

I am using PhpSpreadsheet for a project and am trying to use the exact method for setting column widths. It works fine until the true type font path is not set or cannot be found.

The code I have is:

```
if (EXACT_AUTOSIZE)
    {
        if (PHP_OS == 'WINNT')
        {
          \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Font::setTrueTypeFontPath("C:/Windows/Fonts/");   
        }
        else
        {
            \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Font::setTrueTypeFontPath(__DIR__."/fonts/");
        }

        try {
            \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Font::setAutoSizeMethod(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Font::AUTOSIZE_METHOD_EXACT);
        }
        catch (\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Exception $e) {
            die("Unable to use exact autosize.");
        }
    }
```

When executing the script I am getting the error: Uncaught exception 'PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Exception' with message 'Valid directory to TrueType Font files not specified'

If I change the code to throw the exception in the try block without the function call it is caught by the catch block.